# "Unable to send channel-open request" when using ssh2 crate

Tags: ssh, rust

I'm trying to implement a module for interacting with some network gear over SSH.

My code generates an error about SSH session creation I don't know how to fix.

Here is the code:

```
extern crate ssh2;

// cut some init code

match ssh.authenticated() {
    true => println!("Logged in !"),
    false => println!("Failed to login"),
};

let mut channel = match ssh.channel_session() {
    Ok(ch) => ch,
    Err(e) => panic!("Unable to create channel: {}", e),
};
```

And here is result:

```
Running `target/debug/e6000`
Trying to connect
Connection successfull
Logged in !
thread '<main>' panicked at 'Unable to create channel: [-7] Unable to send channel-open request', src/main.rs:25
```

I see on my device that authentication was successful, but why I can't create channel?

Comment: FYI, your second `match` is more idiomatically written as `let mut channel = ssh.channel_session().expect("Unable to create channel");`

Comment: This is on purpose. Later there will be error handling. panic! is there because I wanted to print error.

Comment: Yep! `expect` will panic with the error message, just the same as the code does now, and will return the `Ok` value on success.

Comment: The issue [Sessions are unable to be returned](https://github.com/alexcrichton/ssh2-rs/issues/16) in the ssh2 repository might be of use?

Comment: Try to keep the `TcpStream` variable in scope until the request has finished.